# C++ - Quais os efeitos do operador & em Hexadecimal?

Tags: c++, emulador

Estou com um projeto de um emulador de Gameboy para android, até agora o que eu consegui foi:

- Identificar o tipo do jogo (GameBoy, Super GameBoy, GameBoy Color, etc).
- Identificar a região do jogo.
- Extrair o título do jogo.

Antes de mais nada todas as referências para construir ele estou pegando [deste site](http://gbdev.gg8.se/files/docs/mirrors/pandocs.html) que mapeou o gameboy por completo, e deste [manual da cpu](http://marc.rawer.de/Gameboy/Docs/GBCPUman.pdf) (fora alguns emuladores open-source).

No trecho de código que uso para identificar o tipo do jogo eu faço da seguinte maneira:

```
if (m_ROM[0x0143] & 0x80){
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Cartridge", "GameBoy Color Game");
        return 1;
    }else if(m_ROM[0x0146] & 0x03){
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Cartridge", "Supper GameBoy Game");
        return 2;
    }else{
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Cartridge", "GameBoy or other");
        return 0;
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente, é até fácil de compreender pois etá tudo muito bem documentado, mas o que não consigo entender é o que & está fazendo, pelo que eu li em alguns livros que tenho ele funciona para pegar o endereço de algo como operador de referência, ou desligando bits, isso que me deixa confuso, pois na pratica esta como "se o endereço 0x0143 conter 0x80 então ele é um jogo de gameboy color".

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado mesmo a referida pergunta ser em Javascript, a resposta valeria para C++? Estou perguntando porque não conheço profundamente Javascript.

Comment: Obrigado por avisar !

Comment: @lemoce os operadores bitwise são os mesmos. Talvez alguma mudança em relação a quantidade de bits das variáveis envolvidas, que em C++ vai ocorrer a promoção de inteiros, e o endianismo interferiria. Tirando esses casos de esquina (que não afetam está questão em específico), o comportamento é exatamente o mesmo

Answer (score 1):

O operador `&` faz uma operação `E` binária, i.e., faz a operação em cada bit (bit a bit) para isso, as duas variáveis devem ter a mesma quantidade de bits, ou o compilador fará um cast dependendo da operação, pois semelhantemente temos o `|` que é o OU binário.

É mais fácil ver em binário (se você tem conhecimento desse nível). Tomemos como exemplo `0x0143`, que em binário é: `0b101000011`, e `0x80`, que é: `0b10000000`. Como pode ver o número `0x80` só tem um bit "1" (o oitavo), logo 
os demais bits serão zerados, e como o oitavo bit de `0x143` é "0", então o resultado de `0x143 & 0x80` será `0`.

Segundo exemplo: `0x146 = 0b101000110`, `0x3=0b11`.

```
  101000110
& 000000011
------------
  000000010
```

Ou seja o resultado é 0b10 = 2; diferente do operador lógico && que resulta em um valor booleano, o operador binário & resulta em um número.

Se fosse uma operação `OU`:

```
  101000110
| 000000011
------------
  101000111
```

Resultado 0b10100111 = 0xA7 = 167

Tabela verdade para `E`

```
1 & 1 = 1
1 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
0 & 0 = 0
```

Tabela verdade para `OU`

```
1 | 1 = 1
1 | 0 = 1
0 | 1 = 1
0 | 0 = 0
```

Note que seu trecho de código está operando `m_ROM[0x0143]`, então o valor desse é operado com `0x80` e `0x03`.